# knockout execute code after template application

Tags: javascript, dom, knockout.js

How do I execute my custom code after all normal processing associated to changing observable's value is finished (most importantly the changes to the DOM)?

I tried subscribing to the method of an observable, but the function is executed too early (the DOM is not yet modified).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a computed observable along with the [Knockout "throttle" extender](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/throttle-extender.html).

The basic idea is:

1. Create a computed observable that is dependent on the actual observable(s) you want to track.
2. Use the Knockout throttle extender to delay the updates to the computed observable.  Even a delay of 0 ms is enough to allow the DOM to finish updating before the computed observable is recomputed.
3. Subscribe to the throttled, *computed observable*.

"Example 2: Doing something when the user stops typing" on the Knockout throttle extender doc page referenced above uses this technique.

Answer (score 3):

The template binding has an afterRender function:

See Note 3, about half way down the page:
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html